# tensorflow dataset builder that runs download_and_prepare with multiprocessing

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

The TensorFlow Datasets [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset) on creating a dataset suggests subclassing the tfds.core.DatasetBuilder. Below is my subclass; it reads NetCDF files and extracts the relevant variables as examples.

How can I improve performance with parallel processing? When executing the `download_and_prepare` pethod, I'm only ever at 100% CPU and can't find any documentation on using multiple threads or cores. The fact that the class utilizes iteration in Python over a generator makes me afraid it's not possible. Is there an alternative approach?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import xarray as xr


class Builder(tfds.core.GeneratorBasedBuilder):

    VERSION = tfds.core.Version('0.1.0')

    def _info(self):
        keys = {'image': image_shape, 'label': label_shape}
        return self.dataset_info_from_configs(
            features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
                k: tfds.features.Tensor(shape=(v,), dtype=np.float32)
                for k, v in keys.items()
            }),
            supervised_keys=tuple(keys),
        )

    def _split_generators(self, *args):
        return {
            'train': self._generate_examples(path=DATA_DIR)
        }

    def _generate_examples(self, path):
        for item in path.iterdir():
            dataset = self.load_tensors(item)
            for j, jtem in enumerate(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()):
                yield f'{item.name}-{j}', jtem

    def load_tensors(self, path):
        vars = list(self.info.features)
        ds = xr.open_dataset(path)[vars]
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({i: ds[i].values for i in vars})
```